# Why the binding is not working properly when using the "required" attribute?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

I have the following HTML code in an Angular component that is been invoked to displayed a record details:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="date1">Date 1 *</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input 
          class="form-control" 
          placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
          id="date1" 
          name="date1"
          [ngModel]="date1"
          required
          #date1=ngModel
          [class.field-error]="form.submitted && date1.invalid"
          ngbDatepicker #da2="ngbDatepicker" 
          tabindex="13">
      <div class="input-group-append">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="da2.toggle()" type="button"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is a input control that is displaying a date value in the format of yyyy-MM-dd.

The variable **date1** that is used on the ngModel is in a JSON format: **{ year: 1999, month: 01, day: 01}**.

So, when the component is being rendered this particular control is not displaying the binding value on the date1 variable. However, if I removed the required attribute the value is displayed.

Does anyone know how to achieved both of this functionalities? Displaying the date value without removing the required attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Cause

The input is not displaying the binding value because it has `id` and `name` set to `date1` and the variable is named `date1` as well.

## Solution

Rename the variable of type [`NgbDateStruct`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model) used in `[ngModel]="date1"` to something else, e.g. `myDate`.

## Example

ts:

```
myDate: NgbDateStruct = { year: 1969, month: 11, day: 2 };
```

html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="date1">Date 1 *</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <input 
        class="form-control" 
        placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" 
        id="date1" 
        name="date1"
        [ngModel]="myDate"
        required
        #date1=ngModel
        ngbDatepicker #da2="ngbDatepicker" 
        tabindex="13">
        <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary calendar" (click)="da2.toggle()" type="button"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## Result

[image: input displaying date]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't notice that one. Now, I changed the variable name that is binding to the ngModel and it's working now with the required attribute as well.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of one control, keeping track of three different attributes (year, month, and day).  Why don't you convert the JSON object to a new Date Object and bind to that.  That object will hold all values.

```
var d = new Date(2019, 11, 10);  // The 11 represents December. Subtract One from the month.
```

This should fix the required issue.  What type of object is Date1? It should be a Date.

Comment: It **shouldn't** be a `Date`. From the [docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/overview#date-model): _`Datepicker` uses `NgbDateStruct` interface as a model and **not the native `Date` object**._